# How to convert Json string to ListView in Android

Tags: php, android, sql, database, json

Hopefully someone can help me understand this, I'm totally lost and can't seem to get my head around this at all.

I have an application that pulls in information from a database, at the moment, the Android connects to a PHP page and the result is printed on the application like:

`{"offer":"Half Price Drinks", "Day":"Monday"}`

`{"offer":"Half Price Drinks", "Day":"Tuesday"}`

I need to convert this to a List view, would anyone be able to advise how I can do this?

I've put in the page that connects to the php page and pulls this information in.

```
public class BarsActivity extends Activity {

     TextView txt;
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources  
         // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.  
         LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());  
         txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());  
         rootLayout.addView(txt);  
         setContentView(rootLayout);  

         // Set the text and call the connect function.  
         txt.setText("Connecting..."); 
       //call the method to run the data retreival
         txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121)); 



     }
     public static final String KEY_121 = "http://10.0.2.2/SocialCrawler/content.php"; //i use my real ip here



     private String getServerData(String returnString) {

        InputStream is = null;

        String result = "";
         //the year data to send
         ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("day","Monday"));

         //http post
         try{
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 is = entity.getContent();

         }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
         }

         //convert response to string
         try{
                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                 String line = null;
                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                         sb.append(line + "\n");
                 }
                 is.close();
                 result=sb.toString();
         }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
         }
         //parse json data
         try{
                 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                 for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                         JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         Log.i("log_tag","day: "+json_data.getString("day")+
                                 ", offer: "+json_data.getString("offer")
                         );
                         //Get an output to the screen
                         returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                 }
         }catch(JSONException e){
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
         }
         return returnString; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly. There're like tons and tons of examples in the internet. http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/  and http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-how-parse and plenty here in this site

Comment: How would the data map to the ListView?  Would one View display Today's offers, or would the ListView displays today's offers and upcoming offers?

Comment: It would just display a list of the offers on that day, I have it so the user has selectd a day, then the day gets passed to the PHP file which returns the offers for that day.

Comment: Maybe someone can help me out with the tutorial, I've taken the source code and tried to put in my information, would I be right in saying the only things that have to be changed are the url of the file on the Main.java, the id, eqid and magnitude, which have to be changed over to the variables in my database?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the json to an ArrayList by iterating all keys->values and use ArrayAdapter